# Convert continuous colors(legend) to color as stepwise constant (discrete colors) in linear gradient

Tags: javascript, colors, legend, linear-gradients, discrete

I am creating a continuous legend (have created using linear gradient). Now I want to convert same legend to look like discrete legend (have constant stepwise values). I have shared the images like how it looks now and how I want it to be looked and also the code snippet along with fiddle link

```
const legendColor = [{
    offset: 0.0,
    color: "#ff0000"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.2,
    color: "#ffff00"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.4,
    color: "#00ff00"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.6,
    color: "#00ffff"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.8,
    color: "#0000ff"
  },
  {
    offset: 1.0,
    color: "#ff00ff"
  }
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const colorScale2 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([0, 400]);
const id = "linear-gradient-0";
const linearGradient2 = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "linear-gradient-1")
  .attr("x1", "100%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient2
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(legendColor)
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(data) {
    return colorScale2(data.offset) / 4 + "%";
    //return data.offset + "%";
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(data) {
    return data.color;
  });

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 88)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-1)");
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/p8mukjz9/2/

How I want it to be looked :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to change only the **legendColor** array the way that each color will appear twice. Each repeated color item should have an offset that is "close enough" to the next color like in example below.

You can play with this array and make the colors in any order (so red will be displayed first from the left).

```js
const legendColor = [{
    offset: 0.0,
    color: "#ff0000"
},
{
    offset: 0.18,
    color: "#ff0000"
},
{
    offset: 0.18,
    color: "#ffff00"
},
{
    offset: 0.34,
    color: "#ffff00"
},
{
    offset: 0.34,
    color: "#00ff00"
},
{
    offset: 0.5,
    color: "#00ff00"
},
{
    offset: 0.5,
    color: "#00ffff"
},
{
    offset: 0.66,
    color: "#00ffff"
},
{
    offset: 0.66,
    color: "#0000ff"
},
{
    offset: 0.83,
    color: "#0000ff"
},
{
    offset: 0.83,
    color: "#ff00ff"
},
{
    offset: 1.0,
    color: "#ff00ff"
}
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const colorScale2 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([0, 400]);
const id = "linear-gradient-0";
const linearGradient2 = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "linear-gradient-1")
  .attr("x1", "100%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient2
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(legendColor)
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(data) {
    return colorScale2(data.offset) / 4 + "%";
    //return data.offset + "%";
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(data) {
    return data.color;
  });

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 88)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-1)");

// create tick
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(10,115)").call(d3.axisBottom(colorScale2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: I just now noticed that it's missing the last color #ff00ff (purple)

Comment: Can you tell me like how I can add the last color (purple) as well in the legend?

Comment: You need to add it to the colors array and change all the offsets so that they are evenly distributed.

Comment: I have added in the color array for offset: 1.0 (same as your example) but it does not show up in legend. Can you edit your example and show the result?